# the webserver stop displaying my php file after first php end tag

Tags: php, html

I have a strange problem .... I made an php (some_name.php) file combined with some html and uploaded that file to my webserver.
The file has the code inside structured like this:

```
  <html>
   <head>
    some html code
   </head>
   <body>

     some more html code

     <?php
     some php code
     ?>

      some more html code

     <?php
       some more php code
     ?>

      again some more html code 
       ................
    </body>
   </html>
```

When I try to view the file/page in my browser ..the page is not displayed after the first block of php code (no errors ..page works well on my localserver) ..so basically I see just the firs part of the page ..not any html code or php code after the first block of php code ends ( first "?>").

Anyone can help me with this? How can I see the full page, why it not execute the rest of the code?

I put this piece of code

```
      <?php
       error_reporting(E_ALL);
      ini_set('display_errors', '1');
       ?>

  <html>
   <head>
    some html code
   </head>
   <body>
```

..........................

at the beginning of the file and still no errors are showing ... and still I see just a part of the page.

Comment: It sounds like PHP has stopped because of an error. Look at the server error log to find out what happened.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely some reference that is different between the localhost and webserver, and you will probably need the error to pinpoint it. If you don't have access to/ can't find the php error log,  You can temporarily display errors by adding

```
ini_set ('display errors', 1);
error_reporting (E_ALL);
```

To the top of the page. If you throw up some code it might be obvious enough to pick out the issue.

**sorry about the formatting,  I can't seem to get the mobile editor to cooperate.